# Why can't I access my EC2-hosted website from my LAN? DNS resolves to correct IP

Tags: networking, router, lan

I am trying to access my [website](http://labelleviemodesto.com) (which is hosted on an Amazon EC2 instance) from my LAN in any browser but it does not work from any of my computers, except my iPad (which is definitely using my WiFi). I also pinged the host and it resolves to the correct IP but I get request timeouts (I did allow ICMP through the EC2 firewall) from all computers I test from, and my pfsense router (primary router that is connected to the modem). Outside my LAN (and my iPad for some reason), the site is perfectly accessible.

Comment: So your network is hosted on Amazon EC2, not a local server on your home LAN?

Is your iPad a Wi-Fi only model, or is it 3G or 4G data capable? Do you have a data plan? I'm wondering if your iPad is actually connecting through 3G/4G. If that's a possibility, try going into Airplane Mode and then enabling Wi-Fi. This should keep the 3G/4G radio turned off, but let Wi-Fi work. This lets you know for certain whether or not the iPad works via your home network or not.

Comment: @Spiff Yes my server is an EC2 currently, and the iPad is wifi only and so it is definitely using my wifi (same wifi my macbook pro is using, and it cant connect to my site).

Comment: BTW, I can reach your site via HTTP, but I can't ping it. So ping might not be a valid test here. Use a browser or curl or something.

Comment: I know this is only a side issue, but if you want to be able to ping your instance: https://aws.amazon.com/articles/1145#18

Comment: @Spiff Ahhh, well i fixed that, now when i ping i get request timeout.

Comment: Just because your iPad is wifi only that doesn't prove it's using your LAN to connect to the Internet. It might be paired with a mobile phone using Bluetooth and be using the phone's connection. Try turning off Bluetooth on the iPad to be sure.

Comment: @MikeScott it definitely is using my wifi, and not bluetooth tethering. Obviously just because it is a wifi only model does not prove it is using WiFi, ill edit my statement in the question to better reflect this.